Is possible to insert a utc iso 8601 timestamp with timezone in mariadb?
To be clear: I do not need the database to remember the timezone of the timestamp, (in fact I want all data in the DB to be stored at UTC), however I would really like to insert my data as ISO 8601 timestamps to remove any ambiguity about how MariaDB needs to interpret the data we're inserting.
We're in a situation where multiple applications in different timezones will be accessing the DB so I really want to avoid any problems being caused by implicit conversions from local time to UTC based on system/connection timezone configurations somewhere.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    delete_on   TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_table(id, delete_on) VALUES (1, null);

UPDATE test_table
SET delete_on = TIMESTAMP("2024-08-06T09:09:45.942Z")
WHERE id = 1;

Gives me a 1292 error, which I take to mean that it is choking on the 'Z' timezone part, other people on Stack overflow also seem to run into this issue with ISO 8601 timestamps.
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2024-08-06T09:09:45.942Z'    0,00087 sec

Does MariaDB really have no way to ingest ISO 8601 timestamps with timezones?
Edit: We're using MariaDB 10.11.3

Mariadb does not have a datetime related type that can handle timezones. Neither timestamp nor datetime stores this. You need to store the related timezone separately, and handle the logic of combining outside of the tables. You would typically store the values as UTC values (again, no timezone is stored so you just need to know that the values are UTC), and convert to local time as needed.

Not familiar with MariaDB specifically, so take it with a grain of salt, but when you choose TIMESTAMP as column type you're specifically opting in for time zone conversion, but using whatever time zone is the default in current session.

@LasseV.Karlsen I know, like I said in the question; I don't need the db to remember the timezone I just want it to provide the timezone with the data I'm inserting so that it is converted into utc correctly.

@ÁlvaroGonzález fair enough, I think the my best option is to set all the connections to UTC, but I just seems so strange that MariaDB has no support for ISO 8601 timestamps in 2024 so I had to ask if anyone knows a better solution.

@Matt Date and Time Literals provides complete list of the literal formats which are distinguished by MariaDB. So you'd use additional code (user-defined function, for example).

you say "with timezone", do you just mean the Z?  or could it sometimes be e.g. +03:00

if you want to avoid issues with converting to/from local times, use a datetime (datetime(3), from your sample data) type.  you will need to remove the Z, but that's simple to do: set delete_on = replace(?,'Z','')
